Would a planet having a sky that is black with blue streaks be possible?
I’ve got a world in a different solar system that’s similar to ours (rocky planet) but the atmosphere is composed of different materials, making it very dark but having some turquoise streaks interspersed, like someone painted them on. I also want this planet to be safe to breathe in for a few hours (or more) without irritation/suffocation, somewhere that characters could roam with no helmet. If this is completely scientifically impossible, what could I do to explain this phenomenon?

Are the turquoise streaks moving or static in the sky?  Do the streaks appear and disappear, or do they stay in exactly the shape/position that they're always in?

To get a black sky, you'd want an atmosphere that scatters visible light as little as possible

@jdunlop i would imagine they stay static unless the atmosphere would change

Serious question: what is the nature of this project that you feel the need to "explain" this atmosphere "scientifically"? The obvious (and only) answer to your marquee question is yes, this is possible! You're the worldbuilder, so you call the shots. We're just here to help you explain what's going on. But when you start asking questions like "scientifically possible", we move out of the realm of worldbuilding and into the realm of chemistry and physics. We don't really cater to questions of this sort. So I think we need a little clarity on what you're really looking for deep down!

Before your question runs into trouble, I would like to point out that we have a Sandbox where (especially) new folks can go and try out their question writing skills! You might get some better advice on how to make this question a better fit for the forum! You'll note that I voted to close your question. This doesn't mean your question is bad. It just means that I think the issue I'm raising is of sufficient importance that I want you to have the time to fix your question before it's too late to fix!

@elemtilas while i think ive got it sorted out now, the project was to be a fan-work based on star trek tng. i wanted the android character, data, to be able to list off information about a planet's atmosphere that they would visit.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Understood! I'm glad you got it sorted, but I think there might still be a valuable lesson. Those pieces of data would have been very good to know in your original question. Those would have helped us arrive at a more helpful answer for your specific circumstance. That's why I voted to close. ST is soft SF, so it's much easier to get something like a black sky to pass muster; whereas your question seems to have been leaning more towards scientific possibility. This is what I meant by seeking clarity on what you really wanted. Jdunlop kind of did you a favour by answering both questions!

Unfortunately Unlikely
The problem is a conflict between two of your desired effects.  There are lots of ways turquoise streaks could be introduced, but

making it very dark

and

[I] also want this planet to be safe to breathe in for a few hours (or more) without irritation/suffocation. [S]omewhere that characters could roam with no helmet.

Are difficult to square.  If you have an atmosphere, sunlight will be scattered.  The nature of the atmosphere can determine the colour, but not the brightness; that's a function of the light being delivered.
I am now going to leave science behind in favour of a "sciency" solution - your planet orbits a neutron star that is accreting gas from a mega-Jupiter that is itself just short of brown dwarf status, prolonging the accretion period for long enough for life to develop on your planet.
The neutron star's emissions therefore are mostly X-rays and gamma rays, without too much visible spectrum light, resulting in a mostly dark sky.  Your planet would also have to have an incredibly thick ozone layer, or else everything on the planet would be irradiated in short order.  I don't know if you can balance ozone absorption and thermal dissipation in a fashion that results in a place warm enough to walk around without a space suit but not receiving a lethal dose of x-rays while doing so, but it's a neat concept.
This also helps with your turquoise; the intense radiation interacts with the planet's magnetic fields to create vast and shifting auroras.
Alternately
An ancient civilization sprayed self-propagating nanomachines into the upper atmosphere of your planet that reflect all light.  They're starting to break down a bit, resulting in patches of turquoise occasionally appearing, but for the most part, just darkness.  The nanomachines emit some of the light they absorb as infrared radiation, heating the surface while keeping visual light out.
Why did they do this?  Hard to say.  They are all long dead, possibly because they blocked all visible light from the surface of their planet.

They didn't disperse the nanomachines in the atmosphere, they dispersed them higher to deal with a runaway Kessler syndrome. It was smart: the nanomachines would dismantle the debris, and use them to build more nanomachines to dismantle more debris. Nobody realized that once all debris were dismantled, and without a source of energy, they'd slowly descend back down into the atmosphere until they found a "floatation" level. And any attempt at removing them resulted in the remover being dismantled, creating more nanomachines...
